# Retrieve all git commits including deleted branches

Tags: git, github

We're trying to recover all commits for all authors in order to try to track extra hours. The issue we're facing is that after branch merges we cant see the all the commits in the git log.
Would this be possible via a process of 1. reflog, 2. retrieving all branches ids and then 3. recreating them (with git checkout -b hash)?
will this recover the branches and their commits? or do we have to commit and push them? can we just commit them to local git to avoid recovering to then delete branches again?

I tried with reflog but I cannot access the author nor dates, so we're fiddling with creating branches but we cannot see the logs using git log anyway.

Comment: Reflog items point to commits.... The same thing that branches do (_point to commits_). What do you mean you can't access author nor dates? If you run `git log` on a reflog item (say, by commit id),  you should see all its history, just like a branch.

Comment: "*…after branch merges we cant see the all the commits in the git log.*" Do you use squash merge? Then stop, use normal merge. With it `git log` will show you all commits in merged branches.

Comment: "We're trying to recover all commits for all authors in order to try to track extra hours." IMHO that feels like a strange way to track hours. I'm guessing you won't be able to extract meaningful data from this.